# Installing odoo-12 on ubuntu-16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, odoo-12

**            ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/eslammofreh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
        execute(self.server.app)
      File "/home/eslammofreh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 258, in execute
        application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 350, in app
        return self.app(e, s)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 128, in application
        return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
        result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1318, in **call**
        return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1291, in **call**
        return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
      File "/home/eslammofreh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 766, in **call**
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1451, in dispatch
        self.setup_db(httprequest)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1374, in setup_db
        httprequest.session.db = db_monodb(httprequest)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1535, in db_monodb
        dbs = db_list(True, httprequest)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1502, in db_list
        dbs = odoo.service.db.list_dbs(force)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/service/db.py", line 375, in list_dbs
        with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 657, in cursor
        return Cursor(self.**pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 171, in __init**
        self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 540, in _locked
        return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 608, in borrow
        **connection_info)
      File "/home/eslammofreh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
        conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "eslammofreh" does not exist - - -
    2019-03-09 18:18:59,091 1892 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed 
    2019-03-09 18:18:59,093 1892 INFO ? werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2019 18:18:59] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 - 0 0.000 0.005
    2019-03-09 18:18:59,098 1892 ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/eslammofreh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
        execute(self.server.app)
      File "/home/eslammofreh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 258, in execute
        application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 350, in app
        return self.app(e, s)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 128, in application
        return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
        result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1318, in __call__
        return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1291, in __call__
        return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
      File "/home/eslammofreh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 766, in __call__
        return self.app(environ, start_response)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1451, in dispatch
        self.setup_db(httprequest)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1374, in setup_db
        httprequest.session.db = db_monodb(httprequest)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1535, in db_monodb
        dbs = db_list(True, httprequest)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1502, in db_list
        dbs = odoo.service.db.list_dbs(force)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/service/db.py", line 375, in list_dbs
        with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 657, in cursor
        return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 171, in __init__
        self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 540, in _locked
        return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/workplace/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 608, in borrow
        **connection_info)
      File "/home/eslammofreh/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
        conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "eslammofreh" does not exist -**

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what problem you are having? Is this an application you created, or a site package you are trying to install? Other than posting a wall of text, could you please elaborate as to what is going on. Also, this might not be the best place to get an answer for your issue if it is related to the installation of software versus software you are creating. If this is your application please consider providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you tested to see the version of postgresql and the status of service

the error indicates that the role 'eslammofreh' does not exist, ie it can not find

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUaN4rEpJDE

Comment: the role 'eslammofreh' does not exist . I added it and it works . thanks